# Bigcartel: Is it possible to add extra dynamic fields?

Tags: bigcartel

I'm adapting the Bigcartel [Luna theme](http://testdriveluna.bigcartel.com/) for a client.

They would like to add a subtitle under the main title on the product pages. In Wordpress this would be done using custom fields. Is there a way to add new dynamic fields using Bigcartel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there's not a way to add any kind of custom fields to display extra information on the product pages. You could consider modifying the Product page theme code though (through Customize Design > Advanced > Product) and adding in multiple `if` statements -

```
{% if product.name == 'This product' %}
  <h2>This product</h2>
{% elsif product.name == 'That product' %}
  <h2>That product</h2>
{% elsif product.name == 'The other product' %}
  <h2>The other product</h2>
{% endif %}
```

... and so on.

Comment: OK - looks like I'll need to hardcode the subtitles for now. Thanks Nick.

Comment: You can also make it dynamic by coding and putting special character in Title and split it.
https://www.fiverr.com/wetechteam/design-and-develop-eye-catchy-big-cartel-store-to-boost-sell